# Comparing a Sympy expression with variable exponent to zero

Tags: python, sympy

I am wondering if there is a way to have SymPy recognize that expressions such as `Pow(positive, variable)` will always be greater than zero (assuming real numbers).

```
from sympy import *
init_session()

StictLessThan(0, 1)      # returns desired output
>>> False

StrictLessThan(0, x)     # returns desired output
>>> 0 < x

StrictLessThan(0, 2**x)  # returns undesired output, but not surprising
>>> 0 < 2**x

(2**x).is_comparable     # From this I assume that I would have to define my own function
>>> False

some_function(0, 2**x)   # does this exist built into the SymPy package?
>>> True
```

I am aware that I can make my own function to do this, but I am curious as to the built-in capabilities and limitations of SymPy.

```
def is_positive_exponential(exponential):
    base, exponent = exponential.as_base_exp()
    return True if base > 0 else False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that when `x = pi*I/log(2)` (a complex number),  the expression `2**x` evaluates to -1 which is not positive.

If you tell SymPy that x is a real number, it will know that `2**x` is positive.

```
x = Symbol('x', real=True)
StrictLessThan(0, 2**x)    # returns True
```

See the [list of possible assumptions](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.assumptions). By default, `Symbol('x')` is assumed "commutative" but nothing else is assumed about it.